# SCM Plugin Integration with Sonar Qube

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-4.5

Can anyone explain me  why we need SCM Plugin in Sonar Qube what are the benefits of it.I tried to find the same solution on below link:-
1. http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SCM+Activity+Plugin 
2. http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SCM+support

But did not get much knowledge about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the SCM Activity Plugin; the core functionality to support SCM data was rolled into the platform in 5.0.

You *do* need the plugin that corresponds to your SCM engine. It provides the specific integration between your SCM's commands and the SonarQube server. That is, it actually talks to your SCM to get the commit data for each line of each file and puts it in a format SonarQube can understand.

Comment: But what exactly it does can u please explain me a bit

Comment: I've expanded a bit. See if that helps.